# How can I run the googlescript code in a sheet without opening the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google analytics report that runs in a sheet.  Using the Chrome plugin, this is set to run automatically.  The results are then pulled into Data Studio on "data refresh".  This works.  However, I want a google script to run in the sheet.

I have written a google script routine to manipulate the Analytics data that is imported to the sheet.  It runs onOpen.  However, I need some automatic trigger more like "onReportRun" to trigger on the scheduled report for the Analytics -> Sheet process.

```
    function onOpen(e) {

      var paramRange= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2:B');
      var paramValues= paramRange.getValues();

    //crunch Analytics data and make two new columns and put them in the sheet.  This works fine.
    }

//need this:
function onGoogleSheetsAnalyticsAddOnScheduleReportRun(e) {
```

This runs when I open the sheet.  I need it to run when the Google Sheets plugin for Analytics runs the configured report.

If you are interested as to how I ended up here, an Analytics Custom Dimension contains a list.  Example: a web page has three qualities tagged against it: "health, wealth, safety" in Dimension 3.  Data Studio and Analytics can't seem to split and then report on list items individually.  So I export from Analytics to Sheets, run code to do this, then import the sheet to Data Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I run the googlescript code in a sheet without opening the sheet

By simply changing `onOpen` to [other triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Answer (score 2):

Google Sheets and Google Apps Script haven't triggers that runs when other code run. Perhaps your best option is to use time-driven trigger to call a "poll" function. The poll function could check certain value on your spreadsheet your could access an API to check if it should update the spreadsheet. The actual function will depend on your spreadsheet and/or the external service that you want to monitor.